# Anomalous backslash in string VSC Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, renpy

So i was working on something and Visual Studio Code has spat out an error.
I have tried several things but nothing seemed to work.

```
while True:
    try:
        file = open("{0}\..\state.txt".format(os.getcwd()), 'r', encoding = "utf-8")
        file.read()
```

[image: VisualStudioCode-error.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses the \ as the escape character so in  your case, you'd have escaped the . and s.  You need to do the following:

`file = open(r"{0}\..\state.txt".format(os.getcwd()), "r", encoding="utf-8")`

If you are using Python 3.4+, as @ninMonkey mentioned, you can also use pathlib.Path:

````
import pathlib

... your code here ..

file = open(pathlib.Path(os.getcwd(), "..", "state.txt"), "r", encoding="utf-8")```
````

Comment: or [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) handles that for you, as well as a cross platform way.

Comment: @ninMonkey very true.  That is only available for Python >= 3.4; so I took the basic method just in case the OP was still using Python 2.7